# How to insert elements in the tag using JSON and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var Jstr = {
        "JSON" : [
            {
                "Eid": 101,
                "Ename": "",
                "Ecode" : "<h>" + "Ename" + "</h>",
                "Eprops": {}
            },
            {
                "Eid": 102,
                "Ename": "",
                "Ecode" : "<input type ='text'/>",
                "Eprops": {
                    "name": "",
                    "value": "",
                    "maxlength": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Eid": 103,
                "Ename": "",
                "Ecode" : "<input type ='password'/>",
                "Eprops": {
                    "value": "",
                    "maxlength": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Eid": 104,
                "Ename": "",
                "Ecode" : "<input type ='button' value = '' />",
                "Eprops": {
                    "value": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Eid": 105,
                "Ename": "",
                "Ecode" : "<input type = 'submit' value='submit'/>",
                "Eprops": {
                    "value": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Eid": 106,
                "Ename": "",
                "Ecode" : "<input type = 'radio'  />",
                "Eprops": {
                    "name": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Eid": 107,
                "Ename": "",
                "Ecode" : "<input type = 'checkbox'/>",
                "Eprops": {
                    "name": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Eid": 108,
                "Ename": "",
                "Ecode" : "<input type = 'select'/>",
                "Eprops": {
                    "name": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Eid": 109,
                "Ename":"",
                "Ecode" : "<input type = 'reset'/>" ,
                "Eprops": {
                    "name": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Eid": 110,
                "Ename": "",  
                "Ecode" : "<input type = 'textbox'/>" , 
                "Eprops": {
                    "name": "",
                    "value": "",
                    "maxlength": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Eid": 111,
                "Ename": "",  
                "Ecode" : "<input type = 'file'/>" , 
                "Eprops": {
                    "id": ""
                }
            },
        ]
    };

    $(".search").click(function(){
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);

        for(var i =0;i<Jstr.JSON.length;i++) {
            var obj = Jstr.JSON[i];

            if(obj.Eid == id) {
                var pr = $(Jstr.JSON[i].Ecode);
                alert("Enter Properties");

                for(var key in Jstr.JSON[i].Eprops) {
                    pr.attr("key", function(){
                        //alert("in prop");
                        var p  = prompt(key, "");
                        return p;
                    });
                }

                var name = prompt("Tag-Name", "");
                obj.Ename = name;
                $('#down').append(obj.Ename);

                $('#down').append(obj.Ecode);
                $('#down').append("<br>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is my jQuery code in which I'm trying to create form elements from JSON object. Now the problem is that I'm not getting any way to append the Properties of Eprops inside the tag in the Ecode

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle with this code? It will be a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create elements in jQuery using the `<` syntax: [jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/)

The second argument for this syntax can be an object attribute name/values:

```
Jstr.JSON.forEach(function (elem) {
    $(elem.Ecode, elem.Eprops).appendTo("body");
});
```